# failed to add multiple PVA Bots as skills in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, power-virtual-agents

I can only add one PVA Bots as a skill in Bot Framework Composer, when adding another, there's an error saying "the skill is already a part of the Bot project"

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a slight bug in Composer when importing multiple PVA bots as skills. PVA exports the necessary files in a zip file with each file contained having the same name as files found in other exported zip files (for example, `manifest.json` is found in each). However, Composer doesn't differentiate between these files when importing. So, after successfully importing the first PVA bot, when it attempts to import the second it fails because it is now trying to overwrite the files already imported for the first bot. The files should be uniquely named to avoid collision.

The workaround is to simply rename any files located in the additional zip files to be imported to something different (e.g. `manifest1.json`). After renaming them, zip them back up, and import the adjusted zip file, and it should work.

[image]

You can track this issue in the Composer repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9213).